# Best practice for loading image from storage in view

Tags: laravel, storage, laravel-blade

I have images in my storage folder that I want to display to the user and I'm looking for the best way to handle this.

I have two options, the first is using `asset()` to load the user image:

```
<img class="avatar" src="{{ asset('/storage/avatars/' . Auth::user()->avatar) }}" alt="">
```

Or I can use the `Storage::` facade with a custom disk (which is called user_data) that I created:

```
<img class="avatar" src="{{ Storage::disk('user_data')->url(Auth::user()->avatar) }}" alt="">
```

Which way is better? Every answer I've seen online uses `asset()` but I find the `Storage::` much better from a maintainability point of view as we are not hard coding the path `/storage/avatars/`.

Is it fine to use `Storage::` facade within the blade template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach using the `Storage::` facade is completely fine to use in your view. Like you said, it's great from a maintainability standpoint and will allow you to easily change the path of your `user_data` if you need to do so in the future. Using the built in Storage functions that Laravel provides also saves you headaches on larger scale applications with multiple servers, or if your user data is being stored on an S3 bucket. It will be super quick to change and manage through disks in your `filesystem.php`.

The reason why you probably see `asset()` being used online often is that disks would be out of the scope and not needed for many small scale projects and tutorials. As it's also used for loading images, CSS, JS and other public files.